# netbeans alterar o jdk do java

Tags: java, netbeans

Eu atualizei o meu java, e removi a versão anterior, agora na inicialização o netbeans fica com uma mensagem que não encontrou a versão 1.7 e pergunta se desejo usar a versão *default*.

Alguém sabe onde altero essa configuração para não ficar vendo essa mensagem toda vez que vou abrir o netbeans ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível alterar o **JDK** que o NetBeans usa alterando o arquivo de configurações dele.

Passos:

1. Abrir o arquivo `netbeans.conf` que fica na pasta `etc` dentro da pasta de instalação do NetBeans
2. Modificar a variável `netbeans_jdkhome` para apontar para a pasta do novo **JDK**
3. Reiniciar seu NetBeans

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809366/changing-java-platform-on-which-netbeans-runs)

Comment: então... né.... eu googlando por ai vi uma resposta falando na pasta **etc** e achei que a resposta era só p/ linux..rsrssr agora achei a pasta, realmente é dentro da pasta da instalação do netbeans, obrigado!

Comment: Eu também, quando vi `etc` já veio Linux na minha cabeça hehe

Comment: Eu tive que salvar o arquivo na minha área de trabalho e depois mover e substituir para a pasta etc, por questão de permissões